# What it is a utility function that it is quasi-concave but not concave?

Tags: mathematical-economics

If we have complete, transitive, continuous, and strictly convex preferences, then all the utility functions that represent them are strictly concave. I know that strictly convex preferences are represented by a strictly **quasi-concave** utility, but I do not know how to prove that the utility function can be quasi-concave but does not necessarily have to be concave.

Comment: I think your first sentence is wrong. In particular, strict convexity of preference implies strict *quasi*concavity of utility and not necessarily the concavity of it.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe it was my poor english, but my question is how can I show that the strict convexity implies strict quasiconcavity and not necessarily the concavity of it?

Answer (score 11):

If you have a single good, so that your commodity space is $\mathbb{R}$, then every increasing function is quasi-concave and even strictly quasi-concave. So any non-concave but increasing function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ will give you the desired counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

For examples of real-valued function defined on subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$, consider:

- **Cobb Douglas**: $u:\mathbb{R}^2_{++}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, where $\mathbb{R}^2_{++}=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|x>0, y>0\}$ defined as $u(x, y) = x^\alpha y^\beta$ where $\alpha > 0, \beta > 0$, and $\alpha+\beta> 1$ is strictly quasiconcave but not concave.
- Transformation of **Quasi-linear**: $u:\mathbb{R}^2_{+}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, where $\mathbb{R}^2_{+}=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|x\geq 0, y\geq 0\}$ defined as $u(x, y) = (\alpha x + \beta \sqrt{y})^{\gamma} $ where $\alpha > 0, \beta > 0$, and $\gamma> 1$ is strictly quasiconcave but not concave.

In fact, every strictly concave function is strictly quasi-concave, and every (strictly) increasing transformation of a strictly quasi-concave function is also strictly quasi-concave. Therefore, every (strictly) increasing transformation of a strictly concave function is also strictly quasi-concave, but the converse is not true. In this way you can take any strictly concave function and consider an appropriate strictly increasing transformation of the function so that the transformation of the function is not strictly concave.